# Why is Jewish God so Popular?

Tags: religion

The jews do not prolyselytes at all.

In fact, originally, Yahweh, is Jewish national god. Jewish scripture almost never claim unambiguously that Yahweh is god of all beings. He never complains about non jews worshiping other gods.

The Chinese, the mongol, have their own supreme God.

So why jewish God suddenly got 3 billions followers while other gods don't sell.

Comment: What supreme god does the Mongols and Chinese have?

A better example is probably Zoroastrianism, which does have a supreme god, but isn't very proselytizing.

Comment: Equating the Jewish god with the god of Christianity is convenient for your question, but are they really perceived as the same e.g. by the respective believers. I rather doubt it.

Comment: Well, the chinese think everyone is chinese and that their emperor is emperor of everything under heaven. It's just a natural corollary that Chinese heaven emperor is the emperor of the whole world.

Comment: @Drux I think it is generally known in both communities that it's the same God, yes. If this is the case with Muslims, I don't know.

Comment: @JimThio I think that is a complete misrepresentation of botgh Chinese religion and the status of the Chinese emperor.

Comment: @LennartRegebro IMHO nothing is "known" (as opposed to believed) about god(s) :)

Comment: @JimThio The Chinese are atheist. If they convert anyone its to atheism or to some secular version of a religion like "Chinese traditional religion" but I think those ideas take time to spread.

Comment: @Drux: Well, yes and no. It is without a doubt the same god. We *know* that. If that god, or for that matter any other god, exists, and if it exists what it actually wants, etc, is not known.

Comment: @LennartRegebro For the record (and since somebody seemed to have deleted my earlier comment) IMHO nothing at all is "known" (as opposed to "believed") about gods. This is not an awfully important comment, but frankly I don't seem why mine is deleted while other parts of the same thread (with opinions of similar importance) remain. On to other business now ...

Comment: @Drux: No, that comment is still there, it hasn't been deleted.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Ups sorry: my apologies to the moderator(s) and respect for your different opinion.

Comment: Not really an opinion... ;-)

Comment: Oh well ... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so "suddenly", it was a process spanning 2000 years and two major religions. But it is possible to make a quick summary of why:

The Jewish religion created two "spin-offs" Christianity and Islam, that ended up being the official religion of two empires, the Roman and the Umayyad Empire.

Both these religions were *very* proselyting, making it of the highest importance to convert people so they could be saved for an afterlife. In Christianity's case this even excused converting people by force, as the afterlife often was seen as more important than this life.

The Muslim empires ruled large parts of the world up until the end of the 19th century, and although not always intensely proselyting, at the very minimum you were encouraged to convert as this would get you lower taxes.

The Roman empire did split quite soon after becoming officially Christian, but the various shifting empires the followed in Europe spread Christianity throughout Europe. And then, by mostly luck, a European happened upon the gold-rich and easily conquered Americas, instantly making Europe wealthy and kick-starting several Christian Empires bent on conquering and converting the world.

As a result, the highly regional god Yahweh has become the most widely worshiped god on the planet.

Comment: Only 2,000 years. My Old Testament must be out of date!

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The point being that expansion and proselyting got started with Christianity.

Comment: I learned that Jews were proselytizing in Babylon Here's some people arguing about the issue: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/was-judaism-ever-a-proselytizing-religion Proselytizing is spreading the religion through persuasion. A better answer might address also why this DIDNT happen in Asia. There are many more people there and if they had one faith it would still outnumber or rival the Christians. I think thats the question thats being asked by the OP.

Comment: @RazieMah But you have to admit that there aren't many Jews in Babylon today, so from todays perspective that proselyting isn't very important for the question. :-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro The Jews are small religion but its enduring. The people they convert stay Jewish. The Babylonian religion is a dead religion, built completely on geography and empire, like most religions honestly. The Jews in Babylon learned to be Jewish anywhere without a Jewish state. I think religions that don't require a "state" spread. This question is rather complicated when i think about...